# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor

Tags: hibernate, constructor, hql, dto

I have 2 tables mapped to entities `User` and `Group`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_COM_USER")
public class User {
    private String userName;
    @Column(name="F_USERNAME", length=60)
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_COM_USERGROUP")
public class UserGroup{
    private String groupName;
    @Column(name="F_GROUPNAME", length=60)
    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }
    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

One `User` can have many `Group`s. I need to model them in order to display the users with all their groups in a table in the frontend like below:

```
+-------+----------------------+
| Users |        Groups        |
+-------+----------------------+
| User1 | Group1,Group2,Group3 |
| User2 | Group1,Group2        |
| User3 | Group2,Group4        |
+-------+----------------------+
```

So I created this DTO:

```
public class UserGroupsBean {
    private List<String> groupName;
    private String userName;
    public UserGroupsBean(String userName, List<String> groupName) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }
    // Getters
    public List<String> getGroupName() { return groupName; }
    public String getUserName() { return userName; }            
    // Setters
    public void setGroupName(List<String> groupName) { this.groupName = groupName; }
    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName;}
}
```

I used this query to return all the groups for each user:

```
String hql = "select new odatabase.service.beans.UserGroupsBean(userName,(select groupName from UserGroup) ) from User";
```

But I got:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [UserGroupsBean]

Although I have a constructor `UserGroupsBean(String userName, List < String > groupName)`

How is this caused and how can I solve it ?

Comment: You need a fully qualified class name in the constructor expression in the HQL given such as `com.example.UserGroupsBean(...)`.

Comment: yes for sure i write the fully qualified class name in my code, the error is that he doesn't find a constructor with these properties (String and List<String>)

Comment: `List<T>` may not be supported in such queries (not sure about HQL but in JPQL/JPA Criteria, it is not allowed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JPQL constructor expression only supports flat results, so you are out of luck. You could use a query like `SELECT u.userName, g.groupName FROM User u JOIN u.userGroups g` but then you'd have to *reduce* the result set on your own.

What you want to do can be nicely done with [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://blazebit.com/blog/2016/getting-started-with-blaze-persistence-entity-views.html). Here some example code.

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserGroupsBean {
    // The id of the user
    @IdMapping("id") int getId();

    String getUserName();

    @Mapping("userGroups.name")
    List<String> getGroupNames();
}
```

This is essentially a DTO with some metadata. And here is the code for querying:

```
EntityManager entityManager = // jpa entity manager
CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf = // query builder from Blaze-Persistence
EntityViewManager evm = // manager that can apply entity views to query builders

CriteriaBuilder<User> builder = cbf.create(entityManager, User.class);
List<UserGroupsBean> result = evm.applySetting(
    builder, 
    EntityViewSetting.create(UserGroupsBean.class)
).getResultList();
```

This will generate a query similar to this

```
SELECT u.id, u.userName, g.groupName FROM User u JOIN u.userGroups g
```

and will map the result for you in the DTO automatically.

Comment: upvote for **constructor expression only supports flat results**

Comment: Any way to workaround this without adding the blaze package?

Comment: There are ways, but you won't like the implementation needed to do it: https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-jpa-dto-projection/